# How to access queryset's fields inside an annotate() inside a Prefetch?

Tags: django

```
class PlayerProfile(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Team(models.Model):
    players = models.ManyToManyField(PlayerProfile, blank=True, related_name='teams')
    captain = models.ForeignKey(PlayerProfile, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

.

```
class TeamView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   ...
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Team.objects.all()
        queryset = queryset.prefetch_related(
            Prefetch(
                'players',
                queryset=PlayerProfile.objects.annotate(is_captain=F('?'))
            ))
        return queryset
```

On the line `queryset=PlayerProfile.objects.annotate(is_captain=F('?'))` I basically want to annotate to each player a field `is_captain` being true or false based on the captain field from the `Team` object.

Is this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with the same issue.

```
queryset = queryset.prefetch_related(
Prefetch(
    'players',
    queryset=PlayerProfile.objects.annotate(
        is_captain=Exists(Team.objects.filter(captain=OuterRef('id')))
    )
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
queryset = queryset.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'players',
      queryset=PlayerProfile.objects.annotate(is_captain=F(teams__captain))
    ))
```